# javascript runs twice

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code in my  section:

```
function showIt() {
document.getElementById("hid").style.visibility = "visible";
}
setTimeout("showIt()", 6000); // 1000 = 1 sec

function showIt() {
document.getElementById("hid2").style.visibility = "visible";
}
setTimeout("showIt()", 7000); // 1000 = 1 sec
```

I am trying to reveal two separate elements. But the code always seems to work with only the first element.

This comes first on the page

```
<div id="hid2" style="visibility: hidden" class="video-arrow">
 <p>Ready for some help growing your business?</p>
 <div class="arrow-bg"><img src="img/arrow-bg.png" alt=""></div>
</div>
```

And This Comes Second

```
<div id="hid" style="visibility: hidden" class="header-button">
<div class="header-button-center"> 
<a href="">
<p class="offer">
<u>YES!</u>I Want To Get Instant Access To Interactive Offer!
<span>&raquo;</span></p>
</a>
</div>
<p class="guarantee">No worries. Our offer comes with a 
<b>30-Day Money-Back Guarantee!</b></p>
</div>
```

Due to the nature of the div layout I can't put both elements in the same hidden div, and... ideally, I would display them at different times.

Comment: Try giving your Javascript functions 2 different names....

Comment: Try learning basic javascript. There is **so** much wrong with that code.

Comment: OMG, so many answers with same explanation. can someone please lock/close this post?

Comment: [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself)

Answer (score 6):

You cannot have two different functions with the same name. Try to change name the second function:

```
function showIt() {
document.getElementById("hid").style.visibility = "visible";
}
setTimeout(showIt, 6000); // 1000 = 1 sec

function showIt2 {
document.getElementById("hid2").style.visibility = "visible";
}
setTimeout(showIt2, 7000); // 1000 = 1 sec
```

Answer (score 4):

you have defined showIt() function twice, its better if you create single function and pass element id as function parameter like

```
function showIt(id) {
     document.getElementById(id).style.visibility = "visible";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have two different functions with the same name in your code, It's not correct.

Try this:

```
function showIt1() {
document.getElementById("hid").style.visibility = "visible";
}
setTimeout(showIt1(), 6000); // 1000 = 1 sec

function showIt2() {
document.getElementById("hid2").style.visibility = "visible";
}
setTimeout(showIt2(), 7000); // 7000 = 7 sec
```

OR you can also try this one:

```
function showIt(Id) {
  document.getElementById(Id).style.visibility = "visible";
}

setTimeout(showIt("hid"), 6000); // 1000 = 1 sec

setTimeout(showIt("hid2"), 7000); // 7000 = 7 sec
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Like

```
function showIt1() {
document.getElementById("hid").style.visibility = "visible";
}
setTimeout("showIt1()", 6000); // 1000 = 1 sec

function showIt2() {
document.getElementById("hid2").style.visibility = "visible";
}
setTimeout("showIt2()", 7000); // 1000 = 1 sec
```

Answer (score 1):

Pretend you are the web browser and read your code, s-l-o-w-l-y.

```
function showIt() {
document.getElementById("hid").style.visibility = "visible";
}
// cool, some code. This defines function showIt

setTimeout("showIt()", 6000); // 1000 = 1 sec
// a to do item.  He sent me a string instead of a function, so in 6 seconds 
// I will call eval on "showIt()";

function showIt() {
document.getElementById("hid2").style.visibility = "visible";
}
// hmm, he changes his mind.  OK, now this is function showIt
setTimeout("showIt()", 7000); // 1000 = 1 sec
// another to do item.  Another string.  
// So in 7 seconds I will execute "showIt()" means by using eval(). 

// 6 seconds go by.
// Time to run "showIt()".  Oh, its a function call.  
// Use the latest version of showIt(), displaying hid2.
// ...
// another second goes by
// Time to run "showIt()".  Same function we called a second ago.  
// Make hid2 visible again. Oh, it already is.  Oh, well.
```

Key points:

1. setTimeout doesn't wait.  It is very fast.  It sets up something to execute later.
2. When "showIt()" is executed, showIt() is the second version
3. It is better to give setTimeout a function than a string that calls a function, especially for cases where the function is only called once.  You can use an anonymous function within the setTimeout parameter list.

setTimeout(
    function(){ document.getElementById("hid").style.visibility = "visible"}, 
6000);

setTimeout(
    function(){ document.getElementById("hid2").style.visibility = "visible"}, 
7000);

See also:  [MDN docs for window.setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setTimeout)

Answer (score 0):

```
function showIt() {
     setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById("hid").style.visibility =    "visible";},6000);
      setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById("hid2").style.visibility = "visible";},7000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason is that you have 2 functions named showIt. The second showIt will overwrite the first one. You can try with different function names.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
function showAndTimeOut (id, time)
{
      showIt(id);
      setTimeout(function(){/* Dummy anonymous function! */}, time); // 1000 = 1 sec

      // or may be you can use below line instead of above two:
      setTimeout(showIt(id), time);

 }

function showIt(id) 
{
     document.getElementById(id).style.visibility = "visible";
}
```

For calling you can use,

```
showAndTimeOut ("hid", 6000);
showAndTimeOut ("hid1", 7000);
```